# enum's rawValue property not recognized

Tags: swift, enums

I'm using Xcode 6's playground to try out enums in Swift:

```
enum Rank: String
{
    case One = "One", Two="Two"

    init(rawValue : String)
    {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}
```

I want to override init so that the enum can be initialized using it's rawValue as argument. But I get an error:

[image]

But according to the [Apple's Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) my code should be correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Martin's answer is completely right.

Here is a different view that more directly answers your question.

In Xcode 6.0, an `enum` doesn't have a `rawValue` property.  `rawValue` was added in Xcode 6.1 but note that it is a **read-only computed property**, so you can't assign to it in Xcode 6.1 either.

In Xcode 6.1, it is unnecessary to implement an initializer that takes a `rawValue` because that has already been provided natively by the language.  If you were trying to imitate that behavior in Xcode 6.0, then you might try something like:

```
enum Rank: String
{
    case One = "One", Two="Two"

    init(rawValue : String)
    {
        self = Rank.fromRaw(rawValue)
    }
}
```

but the problem with this is that `fromRaw` returns an optional enum value because the `rawValue` string might correspond to any enum value.

So what do you do at this point?  You could add a `!` to force unwrap the value:

```
self = Rank.fromRaw(rawValue)!
```

but this would crash if you tried to create an enum with an invalid raw value.

You could treat one of the enum values as *a default* and use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap it:

```
self = Rank.fromRaw(rawValue) ?? One
```

which would avoid a crash, but would probably lead to unexpected behavior on the part of your program.

What you can't do in Xcode 6.0 is have the `init` return an optional value.  This capability was added in Xcode 6.1 and it was exactly this new capability that allowed them to change `fromRaw()` from a function in Xcode 6.0 to an optional initializer in Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 14):

The conversion methods between enums and their raw values changed between Xcode 6.0
and Xcode 6.1. The `fromRaw()` and `toRaw()` method have been replaced by
a (failable) initializer and a `rawValue` property:

**Xcode 6.0:**

```
// raw value to enum:
if let rank = Rank.fromRaw("One") { }

// enum to raw value:
let str = rank.toRaw()
```

**Xcode 6.1:**

```
// raw value to enum:
if let rank = Rank(rawValue: "One") { }

// enum to raw value:
let str = rank.rawValue
```

Comment: Do you know if normal / non failable initializers are not supported, or just broken?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653484/swift-enums-normal-non-failable-initializers-not-supported-or-just-broken?  Thanks -c

Comment: Checked on Xcode 7.0 (beta 3), and `Rank(rawValue: "One") ` correctly initializes the enum member...