# Custom TableViewCell class cannot return an enum value without crashing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In the class that inherits my UITableViewController I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GoalTableViewCell

        cell.priority = goalsArray[indexPath.row].priority as Priority //this causes no problems.
        println(cell.priority.toRaw()) //the getter causes a crash.
        //println(goalsArray[indexPath.row].priority.toRaw()) this Does Work.
        return cell
    }
```

In the class that is GoalTableViewCell I have:

```
var priority : Priority {
        get {
            if (self.priority == Priority.highPriority) {
                return Priority.highPriority
            } else if (self.priority == Priority.mediumPriority) {
                return Priority.mediumPriority
            } else if (self.priority == Priority.lowPriority) {
                return Priority.lowPriority
            } else {
                return Priority.defaultPriority
            }
        }

        set  {
            if (newValue == Priority.defaultPriority) {
                //action here.
            } else if (newValue == Priority.lowPriority) {
                //action here.
            } else if (newValue == Priority.mediumPriority) {
                //action here.
            } else if (newValue == Priority.highPriority) {
                //action here.
            }
        }
    }
```

The getter is not working, as the setter appears to execute fine.

The error I receive is the following:

"THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff518d9ff8)"
There is no text in the console window generated by this error and the application completely crashes and cannot continue execution beyond this point.

The line it crashes at is             `if (self.priority == Priority.highPriority) {`

I think I am misunderstanding something about the getter?

Also here is the enum:

```
enum Priority : Int {
    case defaultPriority = 0
    case lowPriority = 1
    case mediumPriority = 2
    case highPriority = 3
}
```

Edit: Actually I cannot confirm whether the setter is working properly either, as it incorrectly performs for my tableView. if I run

```
    set  {
        if (newValue == Priority.defaultPriority) {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
        } else if (newValue == Priority.lowPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (newValue == Priority.mediumPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (newValue == Priority.highPriority) {
            //action here.
        }
    }
}
```

It actually incorrectly displays the cells consistently and sometimes they all become red when that should not be the case (as I scroll). I am still trying to determine what is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I would set up your var priority as a computed property with a switch to assign the enum values to "priority".

Comment: Check out this answer also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444107/enums-rawvalue-property-not-recognized/26445084#26445084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're crashing because you've got an infinite loop in your getter. Swift does not automatically create an ivar for your computed properties like Objective-C did. So, when you call `self.priority` here:

```
var priority : Priority {
        get {
            if (self.priority == Priority.highPriority) {
```

you're actually just calling your getter again.

You can easily solve this by simply creating your own ivar and using it in your getting/setter:

```
private var _priority: Priority = Priority.defaultPriority
var priority : Priority {
    get {
        if (_priority == Priority.highPriority) {
            return Priority.highPriority
        } else if (_priority == Priority.mediumPriority) {
            return Priority.mediumPriority
        } else if (_priority == Priority.lowPriority) {
            return Priority.lowPriority
        } else {
            return Priority.defaultPriority
        }
    }

    set  {
        _priority = newValue
        if (newValue == Priority.defaultPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (newValue == Priority.lowPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (newValue == Priority.mediumPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (newValue == Priority.highPriority) {
            //action here.
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, I'm not sure why you've got that `if`/`else-if` in your getter; simply returning `_priority` should do exactly the same thing:

```
get {
    return _priority
}
```

You can actually simplify things even further by using property observers on a standard (i.e. non-computed) property:

```
var priority : Priority {
    didSet {
        if (self.priority == Priority.defaultPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (self.priority == Priority.lowPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (self.priority == Priority.mediumPriority) {
            //action here.
        } else if (self.priority == Priority.highPriority) {
            //action here.
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** Doing it that way, you **don't** need the `_priority` property anymore since you're not implementing a customer getter and setter.*

And, just for completeness, I'd probably use a `switch` statement instead of an `if`/`else-if`:

```
var priority: Priority {
    didSet {
        switch self.priority {
        case .lowPriority:
            // action here
        case .mediumPriority:
            // action here
        case .highPriority:
            // action here
        case .defaultPriority:
            // action here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Late checkmark because of exams, I greatly appreciated this though !