# Lister sample project - build errors with the Swift version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I downloaded the Lister "Productivity App" (Version 1.4, 2014-10-16) sample project from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701

I have Xcode 6.0.1 running on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).  The Objective-C version runs great.  The Swift version fails in its build with four errors:

1. /Users/ben/Downloads/ListerAProductivityAppObj-CandSwift/Swift/ListerKit/ListDocument.swift:61:114: 'List.Color' does not have a member named 'rawValue'
2. /Users/ben/Downloads/ListerAProductivityAppObj-CandSwift/Swift/ListerKit/ListUtilities.swift:103:31: Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
3. /Users/ben/Downloads/ListerAProductivityAppObj-CandSwift/Swift/Common/List.swift:126:22: 'List.Color' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
4. /Users/ben/Downloads/ListerAProductivityAppObj-CandSwift/Swift/Common/List.swift:131:30: 'List.Color' does not have a member named 'rawValue'

I wonder why doesn't the sample project compile out of the box?  The setup is as per the `README.md`.

Comment: The project was updated for Xcode **6.1**, as listed in the revision history. The conversion method between enums and their raw values changed between Xcode 6.0 and Xcode 6.1, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444107/enums-rawvalue-property-not-recognized/26444348#26444348.

Comment: @MartinR that point about the revision history is very important, thanks. :)

Comment: I've been studying this project for quiet some time, and I must admit I still struggle with it - personally I think it's a bit of a mess.  Watch code in view controllers, storage UI code in the app delegate, shared library code in platform specific folders, it's a bit of a mine field, and takes forever to untangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is listed as requiring Xcode 6.1 or later. A few things have changed, one of them is that raw values from enums are obtained via the `rawValue` property, whereas in 6.0.x via the `toRaw()` method.

The other errors are most likely caused by similar changes.

So I suggest you to download the latest 6.1 GM version, which is still in not available in the appstore (although it's listed as "available shortly"), so you have to manually download from the iOS/MacOS Dev Center