# Can't run Lister app sample code (Swift) from Apple's website

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I tried to download and run the Lister app sample code which was presented at WWDC for the session 406: Integrating Swift With Objective-C. (I am running XCode 6.1 on Yosemite and this is the most updated version of the Lister app from the sample code page in Apple).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html

However I was unable to run the app in XCode which are best show in the attached screenshot.

1. The app doesn't have the Run and Stop buttons enabled. They are greyed out. Never had this before for any other app.
2. The icons for the Lister app is not showing. Instead there is this new Settings-like icon which I have never seen and have no idea what it means.

[image]

Comment: Are you still using Xcode 6.0.1? The Lister app was updated for Xcode 6.1 which is final now (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460443/lister-sample-project-build-errors-with-the-swift-version)

Comment: Yes, I am running XCode 6.0.1. Hadn't noticed when XCode 6.1 has been made available at the App Store. Will try it out and update the question shortly. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Updated the question and screenshot.

Comment: Now that you've updated Xcode, can you delete the project, re-download it, and then try to run it? 6.0.1 may have misconfigured your project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ReadMe.txt file in the project that you downloaded. Have you read it because I had the same problem and by reading it, my problems were solved.

Regards

Comment: I have done everything that was mentioned in the Readme file, except fixing the iCloud capabilities. Every time I try to do that for ListerOSX and ListerTodayOSX, XCode crashes.

Comment: You should try with the iCloud capabilities. @Roboris

Answer (score 0):

The QuickStart guide included in the project gives the key setting to change in the Build Settings to enable iCloud.

In the User-Defined section, double-click on com.example.apple-
samplecode to edit the LISTER_BUNDLE_PREFIX value.

Change this prefix to a globally unique reverse DNS string for your own
organization’s name, such as com.somecompany.lister.