# Swift enums: normal / non failable initializers not supported - or just broken?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums, xcode6

I have read documentation on Swift's [failable initializer's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) but didn't see anything explicit about the normal, non-failable variety.  Did I miss something, or are regular initializer not supported for enumerators with raw values, even when there is no possibility that the initializer could fail (since the initializer defers to a default value):

```
enum FailableSeason : Int {

    init?(d: Int) {

        switch (d % 365) {
        case 60...151:
            self = .Spring
        case 152...243:
            self = .Summer
        case 244...334:
            self = .Fall

        // default provided, guaranteed to be valid
        default:
            self = .Winter
        }
    }

    case Spring
    case Summer
    case Fall
    case Winter
}

enum ImplicitlyUnwrappedFailableSeason : Int {

    init!(d: Int) {

        switch (d % 365) {
        case 60...151:
            self = .Spring
        case 152...243:
            self = .Summer
        case 244...334:
            self = .Fall

            // default provided, guaranteed to be valid
        default:
            self = .Winter
        }
    }

    case Spring
    case Summer
    case Fall
    case Winter
}

enum NonFailableSeason : Int {

    init(d: Int) {

        switch (d % 365) {
        case 60...151:
            self = .Spring
        case 152...243:
            self = .Summer
        case 244...334:
            self = .Fall

            // default provided, guaranteed to be valid
        default:
            self = .Winter
        }
    }

    case Spring
    case Summer
    case Fall
    case Winter
}


let thisWorks = FailableSeason(d: 60)
let thisFails = ImplicitlyUnwrappedFailableSeason(d: 60)
let andThisFails = NonFailableSeason(d: 0)
```

Note that I broke this into separate enums to make sure that it wasn't a problem of conflicting initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to work with Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1.1) but fails in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3).
It is a bug which has been discussed in the Apple Developer Forum: [Swift 1.2 - Initializing Enums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1101465#1101465).

Two workarounds are given in that discussion: Use the module/app name
as a prefix:

```
let workaround1 = NameOfYourModule.NonFailableSeason(d: 0)
```

Or call the init method explicitly:

```
let workaround2 = NonFailableSeason.init(d: 0)
```

**Update:** This has been fixed in the Xcode 6.3 beta 2 (6D532l) release.